# Net topology issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

so I have topology that looks like that
[image: topology]

And I need to be able to use printer from my WiFi. I use MikroTik router with RouterOS v6.49. Devices from my WiFi(`192.168.88.xxx`) can ping only router `192.168.202.1`, but devices from `192.168.202.xxx` can't ping anything from `192.168.88.xxx`. Also I can't check my printer IP or at least I don't know how. Also Windows doesn't automaticly see printer.

PS. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you intentionally creating a separate subnet for Wi-Fi clients? Or do you actually want all this to be one big network?

Comment: First you will have to find your printers IP through an arp scan or an ip scan. Or even better: read the manual on how to retrieve/change the IP address. Otherwise doesn't have enough info and should be closed.

Comment: From reading your other comments, what you probably want is to have an accesspoint instead of the router, you could do this by disabling the DHCP server on that router, and connect the uplink to one of the Lan ports instead of the wan port. The correct way to know the printer IP is to use DNS provided by the same device as the DHCP server for the printer.

Answer (score -1):

To check IP of the printer - from that PC on `192.168.202.xx` network run Advanced IP Scanner. It should find the printer easily assuming printer is on and online.

As for visibility of it - if that `192.168.202.xx` network is on subnet mask `255.255.255.0` it might be difficult. Ideally you'd want to change that to at least `255.255.0.0` or ideally `255.0.0.0`

Can you connect the printer to your router so printer finds itself on `192.168.88.xx` network?

Another option - change your topology to:

```
ISP Router -> Your Router -> unmanaged switch -> devices/printer
```

Comment: 192.168/16 is private, but 192/8 has public IPs as well so the 255.0.0.0 netmask you suggest is really really bad!

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I can't connect printer to 192.168.88.xxx. To finding printer IP: Right now it's 192.168.202.80 but how can i know if the DHCP server won't give it a diffrent IP when I turn it off and on again? Also I would rather not change the topology coz of 1gbit ethernet ports.

Comment: @NiKiZe - at least I gave a suggestion instead of slanting someone that is trying to help. You did not give any suggestions apart from your opinion. 

kreativv - depending on that unmanaged switch and your internet speed you should not see difference. If that unmanaged is 1GBps switch your devices on network will work on that speed. WiFi will be always slower than that. 
Connecting printer under the router you can manage - you can assign IP address to the printer in router config making it 'static' (router will always assign an address you choose to a MAC address of your printer).

Comment: Yes i know that but the problem is with wifi range. It looks like this: 
first room: provider router + printer, second room: switch + my router. If i move router from second room to first room i won't have WiFi signal(tested). So I can't assign printer IP address. And one more question, won't connecting 1Gb interface to 100Mb interface and then again from 100Mb to 1Gb slow down whole net? But anyways i managed to do it. I've put router into bridge so both routers could work on same subnet and now everything is okay. Thanks for ur comments tho.

Comment: You can always move the printer to the room with your router ;)
Good you found the solution that works for you best.

Comment: Yes the problem is i can't. If I could I would have done it ;d